# How do I find out in which file or module is my function called?

Tags: python

Python 2.5 to 2.7:

```
#a.py:
def foo():
    pass

#b.py
from a import foo
foo()
```

From `foo()`, I'd like to know that it has benn called in the "`b`" module. The only way I can think of right now is raising an exception, catching it and inspecting the traceback (going one level up). Is there a mare natural way of doing this?

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13142074/355230) might work.

Comment: @martineau yup, seems using _getframe(2) would be more efficient than going over the entire stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the inspect module.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# a.py
import inspect

def foo():
    for item in inspect.stack():
        print item
```

-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# b.py

from a import foo

foo()
```

-

```
$ python b.py
(<frame object at 0x2026fb0>, '/home/tdb/a.py', 6, 'foo', ['    for item in inspect.stack():\n'], 0)
(<frame object at 0x1fe4a30>, 'b.py', 5, '<module>', ['foo()\n'], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it turns out the solution is:

```
import traceback
traceback.extract_stack(limit=2))[0]
```