# How to get the file path of a module from a function executed but not declared in it?

Tags: python, filepath

If I want the path of the current module, I'll use `__file__`.

Now let's say I want a function to return that. I can't do:

```
def get_path():
    return __file__
```

Because it will return the path of the module the function has been declared in.

I need it to work even if the function is not called at the root of the module but at any level of nesting.

Comment: What you want is a little bit like cheating the common Python module handling. Maybe you could state your real problem in a different question and see if there is a more pythonic way to do what you really want to do with this?

Comment: @e-satis I'm curious, wouldn't it work if you simply pass `__file__` to `def get_path(path): return path`?

Comment: @erikb85: I appreciate your help, but in that case, I exactly know what I want to do, and the pros and cons of it.

Comment: @Kay Zhu: It would, but my purpose been to create a shorthand, it would not be great, having to to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785479/how-do-i-find-out-in-which-file-or-module-is-my-function-called

Comment: @e-satis you say `I know exactly what I want to do`, which is another sign of not doing the right thing. Question your own believes and you will be surprised to actually find a very pythonic way to solve your problem. Anyway, I can only show you the door ;)

Comment: I don't disagree erkb85. But I always find it irritating when people ask me questions like I am a beginer, espacially when we spent him and I both 3 years on the site, and I'm 80k rep with the 3 top Python questions/answers on SO bein mine, et he is 1800 rep. I do appreciate help. I do appreciate new ideas. I'm just tired of reflex questions that people through condescendently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
import sys

def get_path():
    namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # caller's globals
    return namespace.get('__file__')
```

Comment: Does _getframe process the entire frame stack or just pick the one it needs ?

Comment: It just reaches back one frame on the call stack to its caller.

Comment: I should have said ***in this case*** it's just reaching back one frame because of the `1` argument being passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Get it from the `globals` dict in that case:

```
def get_path():
    return globals()['__file__']
```

Edit in response to the comment: given the following files:

```
# a.py
def get_path():
    return 'Path from a.py: ' + globals()['__file__']

# b.py
import a

def get_path():
    return 'Path from b.py: ' + globals()['__file__']

print get_path()
print a.get_path()
```

Running this will give me the following output:

```
C:\workspace>python b.py
Path from b.py: b.py
Path from a.py: C:\workspace\a.py
```

Next to the absolute/relative paths being different (for brevity, lets leave that out), it looks good to me.

Comment: Have you tried it? This will give the same result as `return __file__`.

Comment: I got the same result as Kay Zhu

Comment: Really? Given the exact code as stated? That contradicts the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), it seems. Quoting: *Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module **(inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called)**.* (emphasizes mine).

Comment: @jro - please read the question again. e-satis looks for the path of the calling module, not the defining module.

Comment: @Gil: got it, thanks. As e-satis has already answered his own question, I'm leaving this as is for people that misunderstand it in the same way I do :).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with the inspect module. I'm ok with this solution, but if somebody find a way to do it without dumping the whole stacktrace, it would be cleaner and I would accept his answer gratefully:

```
def get_path():
    frame, filename, line_number, function_name, lines, index =\
        inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]
    return filename
```

Comment: Ah, I think I now get your question, thanks to @Gil. An alternative might be to call `traceback.extract_stack()[0][0]`?

Comment: A *slightly* easier way would be to use `def get_path(): return inspect.stack()[1][1]` though this dumps the whole stacktrace as well

Comment: @jro: does extract_stack dump the whole stacktrace as well ?

Comment: @e-satis: you can [provide a limit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception) to the function call. I *assume* this prevents further walking of the trace, but I don't have facts to back this up.